# Jmeter:Groovy: Error running groovy script shown while running from windows, but runs fine in mac

Tags: groovy, jmeter, web-api-testing

I have .JMX file which runs ***without any error in the MAC system***. I am executing the same script in ***Windows but getting the following error***.

```
WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 13.
   new File('C:\Users\John\Downloads\projectA\search.csv').readLines().size()
               ^

1 error
```

- I have the latest version of the groovy-all.jar in /lib folder.

**What am I missing here?**

Thank in advance.

Comment: Each ` \ ` in a string must be escaped like this `c:\\users\\john...`

Answer (score 0):

As per [Groovy Syntax 4.3.1 Escaping Special Characters chapter](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters)

> You can escape single quotes with the backslash character to avoid terminating the string literal:
>
> ```
> 'an escaped single quote: \' needs a backslash'
> ```
>
> And you can escape the escape character itself with a double backslash:
>
> ```
> 'an escaped escape character: \\ needs a double backslash'
> ```
>
> Some special characters also use the backslash as escape character:
>
> Escape sequence    Character
>
> `\t`                 tabulation
>
> `\b` backspace
>
> `\n` newline
>
> `\r` carriage return
>
> `\f` formfeed
>
> `\\` backslash
>
> `\'` single quote within a single-quoted string (and optional for triple-single-quoted and double-quoted strings)
>
> `\"` double quote within a double-quoted string (and optional for triple-double-quoted and single-quoted strings)

So you need to change this line:

```
new File('C:\Users\John\Downloads\projectA\search.csv').readLines().size()
```

to this

```
new File('C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\projectA\\search.csv').readLines().size()
```

or to this:

```
new File('C:/Users/John/Downloads/projectA/search.csv').readLines().size()
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
I am using variable as:
testPlanFileDir = ${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}

and using testPlanFileDir to readlines from CSV file:
${__groovy(new File('${testPlanFileDir}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}searchBuyers.csv').readLines().size(),)}

how can I change the testPlanFileDir Value?